# HTML / CSS div :: Why does height: auto = 0?

Tags: html, css

I work on a web page and, dealing with dynamic content, set the `height` of a `div` to `auto`. I know it is wrong to think that the `div` would just automagically expand its `height` to the content that will populate it. Still, this is not entirely a rhetorical question, but I do not understand why, in this case `auto` equals `0`.

Why bother with `auto` in the first place?

Aside from CSS `flexbox` or `grid`, what would be a simple approach to avoid a zero-height div, when I don't know how much (or little) text will ultimately reside in it?

Comment: Not sure to really understand your question but why not use a `min-height`?

Comment: auto height will adapt the divs height according to the content. If you have no content, it will drop to 0px of course. Otherwise as stated set a minimum height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a general rule, I make it a practice NOT to set heights on HTML elements.** Doing so destroys the fundamental idea that semantic markup is able to push content defined later further down the page.

`height: auto` is the [default render value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp) for block-level HTML elements. Therefore there's little point in specifying it. In this state "normal" HTML `block` and `inline` elements will cause the height of the container to expand to fit their height + margins and will take into account any padding or border of the container element.

**A container element WILL NOT respect it's content height if the CHILDREN are removed from normal render context.** `Position: absolute`, `position: fixed`, and `float` all take CHILDREN out of the render context and cause the container to ignore their height.

Whereas `flex` elements and `grid` cells change the PARENT render context so that it no longer is based on children's content.

In most cases, you probably don't need to know a final height since the content will push down the page. If you can't rely on content height being present at render time (like dynamic content) you should create minimums and maximums and make sure to use a [clearfix](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp) if you utilize floats.

**If you're still seeing zero height divs you should ask yourself if you really need that div to exist at all.**